# How to get the program's name that synchronised the hardware clock to system clock during reboot

Tags: systemd, syslog

```
cat /var/log/syslog |grep Synchronise
Feb  8 20:49:22 hwy systemd[1]: Starting Synchronise Hardware Clock to System Clock...
```

How to get the program's name that synchronised the hardware clock to system clock during reboot ?Does systemctl can tell me  program's name that synchronised the hardware clock to system clock during reboot?

Comment: you mean, instead of 'systemd' in the syslog line, you want to know what *it* called to sync the clock?

Comment: yes,how to know which program called to sync the clock?

Comment: I updated your Q and title to better reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/lib/systemd/system/hwclock-save.service

```
[root@hostname username]# more /lib/systemd/system/hwclock-save.service
[Unit]
Description=Synchronise Hardware Clock to System Clock
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/openntpd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/chrony
ConditionVirtualization=!container

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/hwclock -D --systohc

[Install]
WantedBy=reboot.target halt.target poweroff.target
```

So it appears to be eventually invoking `/sbin/hwclock`